# How do you cache 2 php files?

Tags: javascript, php, caching, static

How do I put these 2 files on cache - in other words, once a user loads the webpage, these 2 files won't constantly be reloaded. It will only be loaded once and that's it even if the user navigates across the webpage.

The files do not absolutely NEED to be on separate files) I just want the job done.

I can't cache the whole site because some parts of my webpage are dynamic and some parts need to be live.

For example this is my coding on my home page:
on home.php:

`<?php include ( "./inc/header.inc.php" );?>`

`<?php include("./inc/vis1.inc.php");?>`  <- I want this file in cache

`<?php include("./inc/vis.inc.php");?>` <- I want this file on cache too.

Coding inside those php files: see below:
vis1.inc.php

`

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <div id="vinfo">
            <meta name="description" content="blah">
            <title>blah</title>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
               <div id="wrapper">
                    <div id="fileWrapper" class="file_wrapper">
                        <div id="info">
                        </div>
                            <label for="uploadedFile">
                            Drag & drop
                            </label>
                        <input type="file" id="uploadedFile">
                        </input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </head> 
    </html> `
```

Code for: vis.inc.php

```
`    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <footer>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
                <div id="v_wrapper">
                   <canvas id='canvas' width="1950" height="800"><script            
                     type="text/javascript" src="js/hav.js"></script>             
                       </canvas>
                        </div>
                 <div id="c2">
                    <small>random info<a href="website name"      target="_blank">website name - Owner</a></small>
                </div>
          </footer>
    </html>`
```

Comment: they'd be cached in the server's standard disk cache. if you want the "compiled" version cached, then you'd need something like APC.

Comment: browser cannot cache server's file, browser works with final single piece html, you can try to use frames though

Comment: terribly sorry, you're going to have to be more simple. I'm running my website on localhost XAMPP, what do you mean exactly? and what is APC?

Comment: If the file that you are serving by php (the view) never going to change its contents dinamically with each request that you make to the server  you could consider html5 cache manifest (it will catch the page in the browser until it gets notified that a change was done in the cached page). I am currently using it in a offline html5 application, works great have a few tweaks but lot adventage (mostly in assets loading time). In this case the page content its managed by Javascript only.

Comment: perfect! that sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. So how do I do this "html5 cache manifest"? Is it easy & simple? please understand I am a beginner, I appreciate your patience!

Comment: I don´t know if this will fit in your structure because you said that the request that is sended back from the server to the 'browser' is dinamically generated by different files (some dinamic and some static) so that made the whole response dinamic.

But however this is a great post that explain lots of how it works and you don´t loss anything by reading it. 

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Also u can read this one that contains prob/solutions that you can find while working with it:

http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag/index.html

Comment: thanks! I'll have a look over. Well tbh I just want to simply try and cache those php files I listed. and see if it works. I don't care about the rest of my website too much at this stage. I just want the cache for those 2 php files and only those 2.